# Retrieving SQL Server database schema and objects and reflect in a .Net application

Tags: .net, sql-server, schema, daab, data-access-app-block

What is the simplest way to reflect the SQL Server database schema with all its objects in a .Net application?

Basically I would like my application to scan the database schema and present me all tables and other objects. Further I should be able to explore all table columns and their properties (type, constraints, etc.) as well.

I am planning to use *Data Access Application Block* for my data access needs. Would it also meet the above stated requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You can use any data access method you want - you just need to run the right queries on the database. [This article](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/keithrull/archive/2006/06/17/HowTo_3A00_-List-Database-Objects-in-SQL-Server-using-sysobjects_2C00_-syscolumns-and-systypes.aspx) seems to have a good example of what you want.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server provides some system views that can be used, e.g. `sys.tables` lists all tables, `sys.columns` all columns etc.

MSDN has a [FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use queries on the metadata tables of SQL Server, the cleanest way to access this information is by using [Sql Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162209.aspx).

To use this example, reference the Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc and Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

   var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI");
    var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(sqlConnection));

    foreach (Database database in server.Databases)
    {
        foreach (Table table in database.Tables)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", database.Name, table.Name);       
        }
    }
```